low < high vs low<= high vs high - low > 1 in Binary search
I am confused about the terminating condition of the loop in binary search. I have also seen some solutions where high - low > 1 is used. I need some explanations to understand when to use low < high, low <= high and high - low > 1.
class Solution {
    public static int maxValueArray(int n, int k, int[] arr) {
        long l = Arrays.stream(arr).min().getAsInt() - 1;
        long r = 1_000_000_001;

        while (r - l > 1) {
            long m = (l + r) / 2;

            long extra = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > m)
                    extra += (arr[i] - m) / k;
                else
                    extra -= (m - arr[i]);
            }

            if (extra >= 0)
                l = m;
            else
                r = m;
        }

        return (int)l;
    }
}

Here is the solution from the editorial where I changed the condition of while to l < r and l <= r, but neither  worked

Why return (int)l? l is still a valid index in the sequence but return (int)l must only ever be executed when the value sought is not found. Returning a valid index means it is found.

The Binary Search procedure is a divide and conquer procedure. The goal is to keep dividing the ordered input up until the element sought is found.
Keep two indices start and end (or left and right) which are going to index the two ends of the ordered sequence.
—beg
    B1. [Find mid index.] Find the middle index between start and end indices (we will have mid = floor(end/start)).
    B2. [Is element at mid index less than K?] If K lies between the middle and end indices, we have a new search path to take; set start <- mid and go back to step B1.
    B3. [Is element at mid index greater than K?] If K lies between the start and mid indices, we have a new search path to take; set end <- mid and go back to step B1. 
    B4. [Is element at mid index equal to K?] If K lies at the mid index, we have found K; mid is the answer.
    B5. [Not found!] If none of steps B2 to B4 work then the default answer is an abnormal index to the sequence that can’t be used to index the sequence. This is used to signify that the element sought was not found. (Will only ever be the case if the array has been completely searched and start >= end.)
—end
From the above algorithm, you realize a subtle detail. The algorithm keeps dividing up until there are no more elements between the start and end indices.
Do you now see why the condition l < r does not cut it? If l == r, there is still one element there whose index is both Sequence[l] and Sequence[r] but your procedure doesn’t check this element and simply terminates. Hence your implementation of the algorithm is incorrect.

It worked with neither l < r nor l <= r.

@Biks share the link to this leetcode problem.
